# SP Search -- Managed property missing value

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, managed-property

We have SharePoint On Premise. We use managed property to return results for a multi select look up column.

The results are returned with expected values, except for the default pages of the site. For all other content types the managed property has values as expected, as well as for pages other than the default pages of the site.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Managed properties only show values that are changed or created after the managed property has been defined. Had the Problem on my own (but on SPO) and got expected results when modifying the missing elements.

Comment: Thanks @MP_89. Tried your steps, did not resolve anything. Looks like for the default page the URL returned is for the site, whereas for others it has the full URL ending with .aspx